# Apache Camel : How to iterate over list and call rest api?

Tags: java, rest, loops, apache-camel, eip

I am new to Apache Camel and I am having problems understanding how to implement a simple integration task:

So the use case is

1. Get list identifiers from request body
   ${body.ids} contains the list of my id on which i want to iterate. Example : 1, 3, 65, 6
   How to iterate over these ( as in java foreach ) ?
2. Loop over my identifiers list and call the endpoint with the current identifier; e.g a get person/{id} AND add the response Person to my person collections.
   Which EIP to use to collect each response of rest call and aggregate them into a list ?
3. Transform my collection of person to another type.
4. Return the response

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You have to write a **Camel Route** that listens for requests and does the following

1. Iterate over IDs with [Camel Split EIP](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/split-eip.html)
2. Make HTTP calls, for example with [Camel HTTP 4](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/http4-component.html)
3. Merge the HTTP responses with your message body with [Enrich EIP](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/enrich-eip.html)
4. Use [Aggregate EIP](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/aggregate-eip.html) to collect multiple parts, in your case where you want to re-collect the former splitted parts, you can use [Split-Aggregate](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/split-eip.html#_split_aggregate_requestreply_sample)

If you are new to Camel, get a copy of [Camel in Action 2nd edition](https://www.manning.com/books/camel-in-action-second-edition). It takes you step by step from the basics to advanced topics.

Comment: thanks for detailed list first of all. How could send requests based on previous ones?

Comment: Hello @ddsultan Please ask a new question with more details and tag it with apache-camel. It is impossible to answer to a one-sentence-question - except when the answer "it depends" is OK :-)

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I have post a separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65338202/sending-multiple-http-requests-with-apache-camel)

Answer (score 0):

Here is example:(Which is to call Rest API in loop and prints response - using camel spring-DSL & groovy script)

```
 <loop doWhile="true">
   <simple>${property.loopCounter} < ${body.ids} </simple>
    <script>
        <groovy><![CDATA[
        def loopCounter = exchange.getProperty("loopCounter")
        exchange.setProperty("loopCounter", loopCounter + 1)
    ]]></groovy>
    </script>
    <setHeader headerName="Exchange.HTTP_URI">
        <simple>https://${property.host}/api/<your api endpoint url complete here!!}</simple>
    </setHeader>
    <toD uri="http4:host"/>
    <script>
        <groovy><![CDATA[
                import groovy.json.*;
                def response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class))
                println(" Response is :"+response));
                ]]></groovy>
    </script>
</loop>
```

Comment: We like code and also explanation. Please follow this guide "[answer]" to improve your answer